# RegExp taking too much in checking emailid

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, email-validation

I am checking for a value, whether it is emailid or not using below code.

```
function getEmailId(inputTxt){
    var email = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    return new RegExp(email).test(inputTxt);
}


var sTime = new Date();
var a = getEmailId("kuldeep.sharma@daffodilsw.com-daffodilsw");

console.log("value>>>>"+a+">>>time>>>>"+(new Date()-sTime));
```

It takes almost 55 sec. to give result for the input above, and if I change it to

```
var a = getEmailId("rajit.garg@daffodilsw.com-daffodilsw");
```

it takes almost 3.5 sec to give a result.

I am not able to understand this behavior.

Can anyone please help me to understands this behavior and is there any way possible to get the result instantly.

Comment: Why are you doing a `new RegExp` on something which is already a regexp?

Comment: @Hacketo Must be environment specific then, Safari has no issue with it.

Comment: no issues with chrome as well

Comment: @Jack nodejs is tagged, took 57 sec on chrome

Comment: Btw, good luck with email addresses like `example@example.guru`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^\w+[.\w-]*\w+@\w+[.\w-]*\w+(\.\w{2,3})+$
```

You can simply use this without encountering `catastrophic backtracking`.

[See demo.](https://regex101.com/r/nM7nT5/2)

Comment: hi vks, Thanks, This is also working but Now I am little bit confused which one is better to use, this one or  stribizhev suggested ^\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*@\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*(?:\.\w{2,3})+$

Comment: @RajitGarg the other one will not accept email ids like `abc.asd.-asd@gami.com`

Comment: yes you are absolutely right, but is there any case, which can be failed using this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you pass the `kuldeep.sharma@daffodilsw.com-daffodilsw` string, the regex engines runs into [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) ([see here](https://regex101.com/r/cF0iF9/1)).

The reason is the optional `[\.-]?` that actually makes the engine match `\w+(\w+)*`. The solution is to remove this `?`:

```
^\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*@\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*(?:\.\w{2,3})+$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cF0iF9/2)

Comment: Thank you very much stribizhev, this is working, I have checked this for most of the cases..

Comment: I love the term "catastrophic backtracking".

Comment: Just FYI: see [this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) for more details about "catastrophic backtracking".